# I am unable to call a third party javascript api method in my java code using Nashorn

Tags: java-8, nashorn

I am unable  to call a third party javascript api method in my java code using Nashorn. I can call a javascript normal method, but not able to call third party javascript api method.

Comment: which method are you trying to call, what is your current code, how do you call "normal" methods?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read the [ask] section of our [help]. Also I'd like to ask you to post a [mcve] so we can try to help you with your code.